# how can i go back in android development

Tags: java, android, session, mobile

my android app has 5 pages. page1->pag2->pag3->pag4->pag5. i need to create a button on page 5 to go directly page2. can use Intent object. but then if i press back(phone back button) again it will come to page 5. please help me.

```
public void onClick(View v) {   
  Intent itn = new Intent(page5.this,page2.class);      
  startActivity(itn);                   
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to call `finish()` to finish an `activity` before go to `another` activity.

Example on page 5 :

```
public void onClick(View v) {   
  Intent itn = new Intent(page5.this,page2.class);      
  startActivity(itn); 
  finish();                  
}
```

With this, user wont be able to go back to page5 from page2 when pressing back button.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go back to page1 when you press back(after page1->pag2->pag3->pag4->pag5->page2), you should use a flag like below in Page5:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Page2.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

see the [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)